# How to create a group of image views

Tags: android, listview, android-imageview

[image]

I wanna create a group of image views as below, and I can update background images. I wonder whether I should create 7 image-views on the layout or I should create each image view programmatically, like creating a list? Thanks.

Comment: I suggest putting them in a `ViewGroup` with some adapter. It will be easier afterwards is you decide to change to 6 or 8

Comment: https://github.com/krishnalalstha/Android-HorizontalScrollView try this. It is one of my favorite horizontal scrollview. Easy to implement too

Comment: I'd create a custom listview with an imageview as a list item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say it depends on the data. Will you always have 7 or could you have less, or maybe even more? Do you need to display 7 or can it depend on the screen width? Do they need to be a certain size or can they shrink to fit on narrower screens?

If it's guaranteed to be always exactly 7 and you're happy for them to scale to fit the screen then I'd use an XML layout but if it can vary then I'd render it programatically using a horizontal RecyclerView to show as many as possible on the screen and allow the user to scroll through them.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I only need exactly 7 image views. Each image size can be shrunk based on the screen size. Is it better to just add 7 image views on the layout? Thanks

Comment: Yeah that's what I'd do so, space them out equally to fit the width of the device and it'll look good.